# Angular sub controller not executing

Tags: angularjs

I have a page that loads a whole bunch of customer data. One of the sub sets of data I need to load are client notes. The previous developer just loaded the sub lists as part of the main controller, but I need to be able to use the user notes in other places, not just as part of the main client page. So I have moved all the logic to the notes controller which I think is the correct place anyway.

However, my problem is that my new controller is not executing at all.

Here is the the main client view that includes all the sub views. (The main controller's init executes 100% which is the self.init() you see at the top of this block of code)

```
<uib-accordion ng-init="self.init()">
  <uib-accordion-group is-open="true" heading="Personal Details" panel-class="panel-sm bootstrap-panel accordion-panel">
    <div ng-include="'./admin/clients/clientview/personaldetails.html'"></div>
  </uib-accordion-group>
  <uib-accordion-group heading="Dependants" panel-class="panel-sm bootstrap-panel accordion-panel">
    <div ng-include="'./admin/clients/clientview/dependants.html'"></div>
  </uib-accordion-group>
  <uib-accordion-group heading="Schedules" panel-class="panel-sm bootstrap-panel accordion-panel">
    <div ng-include="'./admin/clients/clientview/schedules.html'"></div>
  </uib-accordion-group>
  <uib-accordion-group heading="Logs" panel-class="panel-sm bootstrap-panel accordion-panel">
    <div ng-include="'./admin/clients/clientview/logs.html'"></div>
  </uib-accordion-group>
  <uib-accordion-group  heading="Matches"  panel-class="panel-sm bootstrap-panel accordion-panel">
    <div ng-include="'./admin/clients/matches/suggestions.html'"></div>
  </uib-accordion-group>
  <uib-accordion-group  heading="Documents"  panel-class="panel-sm bootstrap-panel accordion-panel">
    <div ng-include="'./admin/clients/clientview/documents.html'"></div>
  </uib-accordion-group>
  <uib-accordion-group  heading="User Notes"  panel-class="panel-sm bootstrap-panel accordion-panel">
    **<div ng-include="'./admin/usernotes/usernotes.html'"></div>**
  </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

The bottom one is my new notes view.
Inside that my view it looks like this: (I have tried moving the ng-controller and ng-init to the div above as well with no success)

```
<div ba-panel ng-controller="UserNotesController" ng-init="self.init()">

    ...

</div>
```

The second controllers init is not executing at all. (I have not included the whole controller)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('Common.services')
    .controller('UserNotesController', UserNotesController);

/** @ngInject */
    function UserNotesController(fileReader, $scope, UserNotes, Loader, toastr, $uibModal) {
        var self = this;

...

function init() {
            self.GetUserNotes(); debugger;
        }
    }
})();
```

There is not error nothing. (Added the debugger; to see if it executes)
The user notes are view is displaying, but the controller is not executing.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please create a plunker or fiddle to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Maybe it's due to ng-init being on the same element as your controller statement? You do not need ng-init here either, just invoke the init() method from your controlller's constructor.